# Amazon ECS Public Service discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53

I have a scenario where I have to deploy 3 micro-services on AWS ECS. I want to make services able to communicate with each other via APIs developed in each micro-service. I want to deploy the 3 front-end on AWS ECS as well that can be accessed publicly and can also communicate with 3 micro-services deployed on AWS ECS. Each micro services has a front end so it needs a url.

I have tried AWS ECS service discovery with public dns namespace for services and by having all containers in a private subnet to enable communication between each of them. I have app load balancer for 3 target groups that listens on each port. After deployment of Applications with service discovery enabled, In route 53 hosted zone I could see that

app1.example.com.  A  172.18.27.212

app2.example.com   A  172.18.27.200

app3.example.com   A  172.18.27.150

All three are made as A record to private ip which is created by cloudmap. 
my 3 services communicate each other with url which i will define in config file of 3 apps and i will be using the browser to send some post actions in the GUI of 3 applications.

With the service discovery mechanism, when i do browser actions the url is not resolving as its mapped to private ip in private subnet.

Any solution for this would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> I want to deploy the 3 front-end on AWS ECS as well that can be accessed publicly

And then:

> by having all containers in a private subnet

And you find that private subnet gives a service not accessible publicly:

> when i do browser actions the url is not resolving as its mapped to private ip in private subnet.

Well, private subnet is really private :-)

To make frontend publicly accessible, it should be moved to public subnet OR you have public Load Balancer working with frontend in private subnet.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment. even though if i deploy it in public subnet and having app load balancer to point to 3 registered ports of apps, the 3 applications communicate each other with domain url like this  "api_host: http://<URL>:<PORT NUMBER>" which is present in all 3 applications config file. In that case, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions about what?

Comment: About the current scenario which I have explained!

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: 3 application services deployed in ecs cluster with service discovery. each needs to have domain url to perform post actions in browser and also to communicate with each other. With existing service discovery setup which i had doesnt allow the domain url to expose internet.